# Class in C++ using Macros before Classname

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have the following doubt on class declaration in C++. Why this kind of declaration is required?

```
class MACRONAME cStream : public comm::IStream
```

Why a macro is included in class name. Is there any advantage of this declaration?

Comment: It depends a *lot* on what `MACRONAME` is defined to.

Comment: Usually used in Visual C++ to denote the calling convention being employed. Therefore necessary

Comment: afaik, lots of effort was made so that for most use cases macros became obsolete. However, to know why in this context a macro is required, one would have to know the context and the macro.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg  my understanding is the only possibilty of the MACRONAME in this case can be a namespace. So does we use this kind of declaration when we want to use different namespaces in different platforms.

Comment: Namespaces or namespace-names can't be placed there. Instead I suggest you [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81h27t8c.aspx).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Not true! `#define MACRONAME Foo; namespace foo { }; class ` :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Lite I said in my first comment, the meaning depend on what the macro is defined to. And yuck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it stands for __declspec(dllexport) and __declspec(dllimport) (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75.aspx). Which makes class definition exported when building a dll, and imported when building something that references the dll.

For example in some common header of a dll project there is someting like this:

```
#if defined( _BUILDING_MY_PROJECT_ )
  #define MY_PROJECT__TYPE __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define MY_PROJECT__TYPE __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

And a project defines a _BUILDING_MY_PROJECT_ macro so classes taged with MY_PROJECT__TYPE will be built with __declspec(dllexport) and in other cases when the header is included in the sources of another project class definition will taged __declspec(dllimport).

And it makes it easier to keep code more flexible, for example on non windows platforms such macro can be defined empty.